# How to organize bootstrap grid system in my own way?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to re-organize Bootstrap grid system in my way for working purpose. My code for normal Bootstrap grid system:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
              Left Side bar
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
              Main Content
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
              Right Side bar
         </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

But I want to organize this content for mobile devices :

*Main content* **->** *Left side bar* **->** *Right Side bar*

How can I make this?

Comment: You'll need to use media queries for that along with flexbox. Do you have some css written already?

Comment: can you give me some reference for that ?

Comment: @robjez Not needed, Bootstrap already has push/pull classes for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`push`/`pull`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) classes from Bootstrap. The best way to work with this is to start with how you want the columns ordered in mobile view, then add in the push/pull classes at the breakpoint at which you want them to swap around. For example:

```css
.main { background-color: red; }
.left { background-color: green; }
.right { background-color: blue; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
       <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-md-push-3 main">
                  Main Content
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-md-pull-6 left">
                  Left Side bar
             </div>
             <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 right">
                  Right Side bar
             </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```